# How to download or fetch images folder which has been application in IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis

We carried our images folder in project to IIS application pool which is another server to return fast response. Now When we want to download images,Due to carried other server,folders can not found and getting errors.When images folder was in project folder,it's work properly. How to handle this issue? Create new Virtual path for new request?
thx for advice

```
using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    using (var ziparchive = new ZipArchive(ms, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true))
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < ticket.Count(); i++)
                        {
                            string filepath;
                            string path = string.Empty;
                            var extension = Path.GetExtension(ticket[i].Value);
                            if (videoExtensions.Contains(extension))
                            {
                             filepath = "/files/ticketvideo/" + ticket[i].Value;
                             path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + filepath.Substring(1).Replace("/", "\\");
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                filepath = "~/images/adminticket/" + ticket[i].Value;
                                path=Server.MapPath(filepath.Replace("/", "\\"));
                                /*System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath(filepath.Replace(" / ", "\\"));*/
                            }
                            try
                            {                                    
ziparchive.CreateEntryFromFile(path,ticket[i].Value);
                            }
                            catch (Exception ex)
                            {

                            }
                        }
                    }
                    return File(ms.ToArray(), "application/zip", string.Format("{0}.zip",Id));
```

Comment: what is the path value it is coming when you debug? Did you check the value of it.? If its not base directory you are referring update here.

Comment: I fix it man, replaces dont need to use and work properly.

Comment: Yildiz if you have the working sample please post the code and mark it as answer so that others can get benefit of that.